# Interesting study on $f(x)= a^x -x^a, \text{s.t. } (x>0)$

Tags: functions

[Some Pictures of this kind of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0svdm.png)

So I'm thinking about $f(x)= a^x -x^a, \text{s.t. } (x>0)$

1. It's easy to see that $f(a)=0  $
2. When $x>1$, there is always a point where $x^a$ suddenly gets bigger then $a^x$, and then there's a point when $a^x$ suddenly gets bigger than $x^a$
3. Sometimes the point where $a^x$ gets  bigger than $x^a$ is  $(a,0)$. However, sometimes that's the point when $a^x$ is bigger than $x^a$ (such as when $a=2$). Then, I found out that when $a$  equals $e$ and $x>1$, only $f(e)$ equals $0$, and I think that's the point where $x=a$ changes from the smaller  intersection into the bigger intersection of $f(x)$ and the $x$ axis.

So, to conclude:

- When $0<a<1$, there is only one intersection between $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis, defined as $(p, 0)$. When $0<x<p$, $f(x)>0$ and when $x>p$, $f(x)<0$.
- When $1<a<e$, there is two intersection between $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis. Let's make the bigger one $(p,0)$ and the smaller one is $(a,0)$. I want to know how to calculate the value of this $p$. I need some help thx.
- When $a=e$, there is again only one intersection between $f(x)$ and the $x$ axis. And $f(x)$ is also always $ >= 0$
- When $a>e$, there is two intersection between $f(x)$ and the $x$ axis. Let's make the smaller one $(p,0)$, and the bigger one is $(a,0)$. Again, I need help calculating the value of $p$.
  So can u help me calculate the value of $p$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The solutions to $a^x=x^a$ can be expressed using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). (See the "solving equations" section.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are discovering the beauty of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

If $$f(x)=a^x-x^a$$ the solution (beside the trivial $x=a$) is given by
$$x=-\frac{a}{\log (a)}\, W\left(-\frac{\log (a)}{a}\right)$$ which, in the real domain, has two branches, namely $W_0(.)$ and $W_{-1}(.)$.

You must read about it : it is very much used (type *Lambert* in the search bar of this site : there are $4415$ entries).